# TextField Covered By Software Keyboard And Doesn't Scroll Into View

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

When using Compose with a `TextField` at the bottom of the screen, when I focus the `TextField`, the software keyboard is opening up and covering the `TextField`, and it is not scrolling the `TextField` into view.

I am using accompanist and have things set up so that it **could** scroll into view, but it is not doing it automatically.

I also found that **if the keyboard is already open**, and you focus a `TextField` that is scrolled off screen, it **does** automatically scroll it onto screen. So it sort of seems like the behavior is there, but it just isn't working correctly because the focus happens before the keyboard opens.

Does anyone have a good solution to make the `TextField` scroll into view when the software keyboard opens?

Edit:

Simple Example:

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)
        window.setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE)

        setContent {
            ProvideWindowInsets {
                Column(
                    Modifier
                        .statusBarsPadding()
                        .navigationBarsWithImePadding()
                        .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())
                ) {
                    val focusManager = LocalFocusManager.current
                    (0..20).forEach {
                        var test by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
                        TextField(
                            test,
                            { test = it },
                            label = { Text(it.toString()) },
                            keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(imeAction = ImeAction.Next),
                            keyboardActions = KeyboardActions(onNext = {
                                focusManager.moveFocus(FocusDirection.Next)
                            })
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

With the keyboard closed, if I click a `TextField` near the bottom, it gets focus, then the keyboard pops up and covers it. What I want to happen is after the keyboard pops up, the `TextField` should scroll into view.

However if I then hit the Next button on the keyboard, it will go to the next `TextField` and scroll it into view. Which is what I want.

Comment: is your text field embedded into a scroll view/lazy view? add code which doesn't work for you

Comment: @PhilipDukhov I added some example code.

Comment: this is a [known issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/192043120), see this thread for possible workarounds

Answer (score 0):

I had a similiar issue. This seems to be a bug in Compose. To fix it, add the following in your activity's onCreate:

`window.setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE)`

Comment: I have this in my code, but it doesn't fix the issue I am having. I found it is needed to make sure accompanist Ime padding works on some devices.